# Помогите сверстать блок

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Коллеги, добрый день.

Есть макет. Сверстал header, "hero" секцию и секцию с карточками товаров ниже.
Встрял с реализацией нижней части "hero" секции (или это секция относится к секции с карточками товаров) - собственно в этом и есть мой вопрос. Речь об изогнутом бордере на котором изображены круглые бейджи.

К какой секции это место отнести?
И собственно что вы можете посоветовать по реализации?

Буду признателен за любую помощь!

Скрин прилагается.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте свой код в вопрос, без кода вряд ли кто с нуля будет вам всё расписывать.

Comment: p.s. прикольный макет с ежиками :) а можно целиком его посмотреть где-то?

Comment: Полностью к сожалению не могу предоставить)

Comment: А по поводу кода: расписывать не надо. Есть вообще идеи как это место можно реализовать?

Comment: Я бы это выделил в отдельный блок, наверное, а сверстать можно с помощью SVG.

Comment: Попробую. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

ну вариантов не так что бы прям много.

в качестве кругляшков с текстом конечно вертикальные flex"ы

---

а на счет бордюра

1. конечно можно почитерить с SVG
2. на фон картинку
3. пусть это будет контейнер-обёртка для кругляшков, примерно такой:

`border-top: 1px; width 1000%; height: 1000%; border-radius: 1000%;`

разумеется его края надо будет overflow: hiden; обернув во что то с width: 100%;

+ боковыми padding'ами зажать контент в его центре, при этом топовый паддинг стоит как минимум обнулить, мб еще кругляшки высунуть на `top: -50%;` (50% своей высоты разумеется).

ну и под кругляшками конечно box-shadow: white

я это вижу как то так...

Comment: Попробую! Спасибо большое!